# Docker-compose auto-complete in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, docker-compose

I can't seem to find a plugin for auto-completion inside `docker-compose.yml` files, for Intellij Idea.

Is there anything existing for that ?

Comment: I am working on this right now, it will be available in one of the first EAPs for IDEA 2017.2 stream roughly at the end of April 2017. Please track [this youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171031) for a progress. HTH